# Lottie full screen photo Screen adaptation - Full screen issue at low screen resolution

Tags: android, lottie

I'm using Lottie photo Screen adaptation. The animation below is divided into two layers. The upper layer is the falling petals, The lower layer is a full-screen star photo.

The problem is that the underlying image doesn't fill the full screen at 480x800 resolution. There is no problem at 720x1080 and 1080x1920.

What is more strange is that falling petals can fall in full screen.

How can this be fixed?

**1080x1920**
[image]

**720x1080**
[image]

**480x800**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

set scale type to imageview

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: I tried to find a api to get that picture, but he did not provide.  Thank you